# Data of SAP Web Intelligence Report or Universe through REST

Tags: javascript, rest, odata, business-objects

Our task is to create a webapp which displays dashboards with D3.js based on the data of SAP BOXI Web Intelligence Reports or Universes. What I've found so far to get the results:

**Using universes**: 
 1. create a `query` from the client side in xml 
 2. get the `flow` of this query
3. use a a semi-OData protocol to get the results

**Examples:** 
*1. Creating query with XML:*

```
'<query xmlns="http://www.sap.com/rws/sl/universe" dataSourceType="unv" dataSourceId="<id>">' +
                    '<querySpecification version="1.0">' +
                    '<queryData>' +
                    '<resultObjects>' +
                    '<resultObject id="DO1"/>' +          
                    '<resultObject id="DO2"/>' +
                    '<resultObject id="DO3"/>' +            
                    '</resultObjects>' +
                    '</queryData>' +
                    '</querySpecification>' +
                    '</query>'
```

*2. Top10 results URI*: `.../sl/v1/queries/<universe-id>/data.svc/Flows0?$top=10`

---

**Using reports**:
 1. find the `VTable` element of a report
 2. extract its `dataset`

 **Examples**: 
   *Dataset URI:* `.../raylight/v1/documents/2903515/reports/1/elements/33/dataset`

Is there any other (hopefully easier to implement and maintain) approach to achieve our goal?

Comment: Can you clarify your requirements ? With what you are saying, I don't see how this can be simpler.

Comment: @ArnaudDevelay Sadly I can't be more specific. The requirements are what I've written: Somehow get the data of a BOXI report or Universe (preferably with no server-side code) and display the information using dashboards. BOXI is used to handle the authentication/authorization. Thank you for your time!